# why does pushing an array onto an array give an array within an array within an array

Tags: multidimensional-array

In JavaScript, when I push an array onto an array, I seem to get an extra level of indirection. That is, there seems to be an array within an array within an array - at least according to the Google Apps Script debugger. I'm trying to end of with a three dimensional array, but I require 4 indexes to get the length of the inner most array. Does this make sense to anybody?

Comment: if you want to push at the same level, you should use concat. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?retiredLocale=tr

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, push inserts the element or object as the last item of the array regardless of how many elements it contains. In array1 below, "c" occupies the last position. Its index is 2.  When we array1.push(array2), array2 is moved into index 3 of array 1:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3];
array1.push(array2);
console.log(array1); # result: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

As Hadar C said, use concat(), instead:

```
let array3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
let array4 = [1, 2, 3];
array3 = array3.concat(array4); # result: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3 ]
```